# HttpClient Request takes too long - Response status code does not indicate success: 404

Tags: exception, windows-phone-8, http-status-code-404, dotnet-httpclient

After approximately one minute the HttpRequestException "Response status code does not indicate success: 404" is thrown. I know, I have to reduce data and query time. I will do this in a second step!
Is it not possible to extend the time until the exception is thrown?

Thanks for help!
Michael

Comment: Not sure I follow the question. Not found means not found, what good would extending the timeout do?

Comment: Hi. I get no "not found" exception. The method runs successfully  on Service, but it takes longer than one minute. The windows phone 8 (http client) throws the HttpRequestException after one minute. This time I want to extend.

Comment: Do you understand that an HTTP 404 status means that there was a server-side "not found" error?

Answer (score 0):

I use the Windows Runtime version of HttpClient (Windows.Web.Http.HttpClient instead System.Net.Http.HttpClient), which is a newer API. I had to update the app to WP 8.1 Silverlight. Now it works fine!